# Problems with a passive network setup used with a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, passive-networks, pulse, square

Here is the circuit in my mind before I ask my question:

[image]
The microcontroller outputs 0..5v pulse train at 3kHz.
First of all, the setup between the points A and X needs to be fed by a 3kHz alternating square-wave(this is a must) for some reason about chemistry, reactions ect. which I don't need to know the reason why.

The aim is to figure out the R_unkonwn roughly(R_unknown can change slowly and it should be monitored and measured roughly by a microcontroller).

The idea is to employ a voltage-divider and send the data to AnalogInput_1 and AnalofInput_2. Since we know and can set R_known, and if we are able to send the voltage at point A and point B to the microcontroller's analog input the microcontroller can be coded to derive the R_unknown.

C1 and R1 is to obtain square wave from the 0..5V pulse output of the microcontroller. I put D1 and D2 to only pass the positive side of the square wave since the microcontroller's analog inputs can only be fed by 0 to 5V. As for as I know the input impedance of the uC inputs are 100Meg.

But as you see in the spice simulation I don't get nice pulses as inputs. However my aim was to read the amplitudes at A and B and derive the R_unknown from these(by knowing R_known). But the outputs at AnalogIn_1 and AnalogIn_2 are neither sharp pulses nor I could get rid of the negative voltages.

How can I fix or optimize this circuit so that I can have better pulses(with flat ON part) as inputs by clamping negative voltages?

Comment: You are outputting a PWM through a high pass RC filter? Let's start there. Why??? I gather this is something about chemistry? But if you can't describe that process, I suspect it will be hard to be of any useful help.

Comment: Yes the setup between A and X (R_known+R_unknown) should be fed by an alternating voltage or square wave. That's why. The process is chemical water stuff I don't know that part. But resistive. Lets call it R_unknown.

Comment: And you imagine that you should be able to input a square wave output from your I/O pin, through a high-pass RC filter, and get exactly a square wave out from that?

Comment: Thats how I thought with a pure resistive network. If you have an idea using a transistor or an opamp that also fine. The idea is to measure R_unknown by the microcontroller.

Comment: I gather you want a square wave to drive your chemistry, retaining the given pulse *width*, but that you don't really care exactly what voltage magnitudes result except that they must be exactly centered around zero volts. So a \$0-3\:\textrm{V}\$ (DC shifted) PWM output can result in a \$\pm 1\:\textrm{V}\$, or even \$\pm 20\:\textrm{V}\$, just so long as the mid-point is \$0\:\textrm{V}\$? You don't care about the magnitude? Just the center (and width)? Do you care about the width, in fact? Or will it always be 50%?

Comment: Those diodes should be removed. For microcontroller A-to-D input (0-to-5 V), use an intermediate linear high-impedance amplifier that accepts input around 0v, and that adds a +2.5v DC offset voltage at its output.

Comment: @jonk Yes the pulse width will be constant; I will use the amplitudes of the pulses from the point A and the point B.  Output can result +-2.5V or more±20V, so long as the mid-point is 0V. Yes so only the relative magnitudes matter to derive R_unknown.

Comment: Why don't you just directly apply your microcontroller's pulse output to one side of the chemistry and apply a driven \$2.5\:\textrm{V}\$ output voltage as the "ground" of that chemistry? (Point \$X\$ in your "setup" box.)

Comment: @jonk Sounds really nice can you draw and write as an answer? Do u mean subtracting 2.5V later in the uC right?

Comment: The MCU *analog* inputs are almost certainly not megaohm impedance.  In some devices when operating their ADCs at a fast rate, the impedance may be well under 10K, possibly even under 1K.  **Check the data sheet**, or better use a buffer amp as Glen recommended.

Comment: The strange spiky waveform is the result of the unrealistically high load impedance on the diodes. You're basically seeing the exaggerated effects of diode parasitics (capacitance, switching time and leakage currents). Note that connecting diodes like this does put a DC bias on your chemistry experiment, which is why you really need to take a different approach altogether. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the capacitor in the wrong place. Try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMHH5P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The key is to make sure that the R-C time constant is a couple of orders of magnitude greater than your sample period in order to get accurate results. As soon as possible after the pulse output changes state, sample both analog inputs and perform your calculation. The values shown give you a time constant of about 0.32 s, and it should be possible to sample the inputs within a few tens of µs.

---

The above circuit is not simulatable in CircuitLab. Here's one that is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNIbCY.png)</sup>

With these component values (mainly the resistors) the voltage across R_chemistry is about 1.5 Vpp (±0.781 V).

Comment: I can also take the max values(amplitudes) of a longer period(like a second) in the code instead right?

Comment: You could do that if your analog sampling is not synchronized with the pulse output. But it would be better to sample synchronously. This eliminates random errors, and systematic errors can be calibrated out. But I was under the impression that you were just looking for relative changes in value, rather than absolute measurements.

Comment: voltage drops dramatically to 0.8V because of Xc. If the voltage is low for the setup tomorrow what can I do to for a higher voltage? an npn just after the pulse out?

Comment: Xc for a 10 uF capacitor is only about 5.3 ohms @ 3 kHz. Are you sure that's what the problem is?

Comment: oh thats due to R_known i guess then  u re right. but in case  if i need more power an npn in common emitter config would be ok?

Comment: @user134429 If you needed a better driver than the output pin of an MCU, then it's likely that you'd need both *push* and *pull*. So a single NPN probably wouldn't be so good. But I don't see why you do need a better driver. The CMOS output impedance probably isn't more than a few hundred Ohms and Dave's got your \$22\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ in series with that, and you've got an ADC monitoring the output too, so output impedance of your MCU probably isn't an issue. There may be possible ADC sampling/input loading. Chris mentioned the idea of a buffer for that. But perhaps you don't need it?

Comment: @jonk what if I find out that I need +-5V. Measuring R_unknown just one thing the other issue could be I might need higher voltage swings for the chemical stuff to work. Btw what is the equation here for R_unkonwn in terms of monitored analog inputs??? Thers drop at C so Im confused to formulate that.

Comment: @user134429 You will have to wait a few seconds during start up because it will take that much time, about \$7-8\tau\$, for the whole thing to settle the capacitor's voltage. Prior to that, there *will* be a DC current that you have to accept. But once that settles out, just measure the peak to valley voltages. That will be a simple divider equation. If \$R_X=10\:\textrm{k} \Omega\$ then about \$V_{CC}\cdot\frac{10\:\textrm{k} \Omega}{10\:\textrm{k}\Omega+22\:\textrm{k}\Omega}\approx 1.56\:\textrm{V}\$ peak to peak. (Discounting pin and capacitor impedances.)

Comment: (Discounting capacitor impedances) but that will introduce error

Comment: R_unknown = ? in terms of R_known and analog inputs? including cap drop

Comment: @user134429 I'm not sure how you mean "nonlinearity." (Too many meanings.) Non-linearity would be if you had your diodes in there. The capacitor itself will charge up within a few seconds and then will be quite linear (small signal) in behavior. It's impedance is ignorable. So, probably, is the impedance at the I/O pin of the MCU. And the unmentioned non-resistive aspects of your chemistry, besides. If accuracy matters, you will have to calibrate everything. But there is far too little info about what you need/want, anyway, to say a lot about applicability to your needs.

Comment: Your requirements seem to be drifting, which makes this whole thing a moving target, and too much trouble to bother with. You started out wanting *"to figure out the R_unkonwn roughly"* (your words). Now you seem to want every last iota of precision. Also, you were just looking for a measurement before, and now you *"might need higher voltage swings for the chemical stuff to work."* Go figure out what you **really** need, and then come back here for help.

Comment: @user134429 Your ADC input is read twice per cycle (or more often.) You take the difference. You use that count value times a factor to figure out volts, \$V_X\$. Then compute \$R_X=22\:\textrm{k}\Omega\cdot\frac{V_X}{5\:\textrm{V}-V_X}\$. But you should have been able to work that out on your own.

Comment: @DaveTweed i dont need precision i just want to understand why we can ignore drop at C to explain if someone ask me. if i can mathematically show that i mean

Comment: I already explained that Xc is about 3 orders of magnitude lower than all of the other impedances in the circuit. What else do you need?

Answer (score -1):

Your controller will output square waves. Remove R1 and C1 from the circuit and your over and undershoots will be eliminated. D1 and D2 also appear to be superfluous. They will certainly cause errors on the low side of the range due to voltage drop.

Comment: What do you mean? uP? If I remove R1 C1 D1 and D2 what is left?

Comment: You stated that the controller ouputs a 0.5 volt pulse train. Is this not the case? I edited my response to say controller to avoid confusion

Comment: I read the OP to say \$0\:\textrm{V}\$ ***to*** \$5\:\textrm{V}\$.

Comment: 0V to 5V pulses from uC.

Comment: Ok - so they are square waves. Remove the RC as I stated.

Comment: What about the requirement for zero DC current through the "chemistry"?

Comment: @Dave - The stated requirement is square waves through the chemistry. Did I miss something about a zero DC current?

Comment: I took the zero DC current as implied; after going through a long digression that should have been in the OP's question at the outset.

Comment: It is both stated outright -- *"... needs to be fed by a 3kHz alternating square-wave (this is a must)"* -- and reinforced by the fact that the OP used a capacitor in the first place.